# Vocabulary of cycles in graph theory: closed walk, closed trek, closed trail and closed path

Tags: graph-theory, terminology, hamiltonian-path

In graph theory, walks can be described with these terms according to the [glossary of graph theoretic terms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glossary_of_graph_theory_terms), [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_(graph_theory)), and [this](http://planetmath.org/closedWalkTrekTrailPath) page.

- **walk**: an alternating sequence of vertices and edges, starting and ending at a vertex, in which each edge is adjacent in the sequence to its two endpoints
- **trek**: a walk that does not backtrack, i.e. no two successive edges are the same
- **trail**: a trek where all edges are distinct
- **path**: a trail where all vertices are distinct (except maybe the first and last)

---

I am trying to see if there is there are specific names for the closed versions, ie when the first and last vertices are the same:

- **(1) closed walk**
- **(2) closed trek**
- **(3) closed trail**
- **(4) closed path**
- **(5)** plus the term corresponding to the non-specification of the "first" and "last" vertex (because it's a cycle, it does not "matter" where we start ie the thing called a [circuit on this page](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GraphCycle.html))

So far I have read these terms:

- **cycle**
- **elementary cycle**
- **circuit**
- **tour**
- ...

but I do not know which one correspond to **(1)**, **(2)**, **(3)**, **(4)** and **(5)**.

---

**Question:** So in short, what are the most commonly accepted mathematical terms (if they exist) to designate **(1)**, **(2)**, **(3)**, **(4)** and **(5)**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- **Closed walk**: cycle.
- **Closed path**: simple cycle, a.k.a. elementary cycle.
- **Closed trail**: circuit.

*Tour* is just a synonym for *trek*.

I have never heard of a shortcut for *closed tour*. Also, I am not convinced that this definition of circuit (where the initial point is not specified) is universally accepted. I have never encountered a text where the authors would take for granted that such or such words would *imply* that the initial point doesn't matter. If needed, they would specify it.